# cortex debug samd21 cortex M0+

Tags: debugging, vscode-debugger, cortex-m, atmel

Is anyone succesfully debugging a cortex M0+ board with vscode and cortex debug ? Let me explain, I have a personal borad build with an `atsamd21e18a`, when I start debug session it's ok debug starts normally, I put a breakpoint begining of my setup function and, but my code doesn't work properly, specially when I use `Wire` to comunicate with captor in i2C or `SerialUSB` to print something in terminal.

For example

```
void setup() {
  int test = 0;
  ... other lines ....
  Wire.beginTransmission(DSO_ADDRESS); 
  Wire.write(0x18);                    
  Wire.write(0x02);                   
  Wire.endTransmission();    
  delay(20); 
  ...
}
```

If I try to pass `Wire.beginTransmission(DSO_ADDRESS);`  in debug mode my program doesn't reach next instruction `Wire.write(0x18);` in this case. The code works perfectly in normal mode my i2c captor works I got values. I have the same result if I try to pass `while(!SerialUSB)`.

Does anyone have already debug samd21 with atmel ice and vscode plus cortex debug openocd ?

Comment: `while(!SerialUSB)` is a well-known trouble maker in serial debugging. If the USB-to-Serial connection is implemented in software, debugging interferes with USB timing. Since the device doesn't answer to USB requests in time, the host gives up. So the serial connection will never initialize and above loop gets stuck. The solution is to set the first break point after the `while` loop, possibly also adding `delay(2000)` to ensure USB has time to initialize. I can't tell whether it also affects your issues with `Wire`.

Comment: @Codo Ok I understand for `SerialUSB` but I've the same problem with `Wire` do you think this is the same issue ?

Comment: I can't really tell. Use the debugger and stop the program execution and check where exactly it's stuck within the Arduino/Wire code.